# Django TypeError at /signup 'user_password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error whenever I'm trying to create a new user.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'securewitness')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\****\Documents\GitHub\****\app\securewitness\views.py" in signup
  35.                        user_password = request.POST["user_password"])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __init__
  453.                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Exception Type: TypeError at /signup
Exception Value: 'user_password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Here's my signup.html page

```
{% extends "securewitness/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Sign Up Page</h1>
    <form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" id="signup" method="post" action="{% url 'securewitness:signup' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="user_name">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" value="" size="25">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="user_password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_password" value="" size="25">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-controls">
            <input type="submit" name="signup" value="signup" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from securewitness.models import Bulletin
from securewitness.models import Folder
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Q
....


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newUser = User(user_name = request.POST["user_name"],
                       user_password = request.POST["user_password"])
        newUser.save()
    return render(request, 'securewitness/signup.html')


...

def createbulletin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newBulletin = Bulletin(bulletin_name=request.POST["bulletin_name"],
                               bulletin_description=request.POST["bulletin_description"],
                               bulletin_location=request.POST["bulletin_location"],
                               bulletin_date=timezone.now(),
                               bulletin_author=request.POST["bulletin_author"],
                               folder=Folder.objects.get(id=request.POST["bulletin_folder"]))
        newBulletin.save()
    b = Bulletin.objects.all()
    folders = Folder.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'securewitness/createbulletin.html', {'bulletin_list': b, 'folders': folders})


def createfolder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newfolder = Folder(folder_name=request.POST["name"],
                           folder_description=request.POST["description"],
                           author=request.POST["author"])
        newfolder.save()
        return render(request, 'securewitness/createfolder.html', {'message': 'Successfully created folder'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'securewitness/createfolder.html', {})


....
```

The only reason I incorporate both createfolder and createbulletin is because thsoe two fucntions do work when I try to create a new folder or bulletin.

here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.




class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name


class Folder(models.Model):
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    folder_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.folder_name


class Bulletin(models.Model):
    bulletin_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bulletin_description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    bulletin_location = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    bulletin_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bulletin_author = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, verbose_name="containing folder", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.bulletin_name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using your `User` model, you're using Django's:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Django's `User` does not have a `user_name` or `user_password` field.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was such a great find!